# Cobertura Ant merge reports

Tags: ant, merge, cobertura

I need to merge coverage.xml reports generated by Cobertura. Cobertura creates reports in following structure:

```
./coberturaReports/module1/coverage.xml
./coberturaReports/module2/coverage.xml
```

I found bits and pieces from google, but I could still not make sense of it. Does anyone know how to merge these two Cobertura coverage.xml files into one?

Comment: as far as I remember you can't merge coverage files in cobertura

Comment: <cobertura-merge>
    <fileset dir="${test.execution.dir}">
        <include name="server/cobertura.ser" />
        <include name="client/cobertura.ser" />
    </fileset>
</cobertura-merge>

Comment: I took the above from cobertura page, but I dont know how to use it.

Comment: you can't merge the xml reports, you can only merge the .ser files,those are generated directly by cobertura. The xml files are created from those

Comment: Can you merger the .ser file just after instrumentation? I have two module- two jar but one deploy.